# Export to PDF in Django

Tags: html, css, django, pdf

So I'm trying to export a section of a website to PDF, and Im able to export the HTML successfully, but the CSS codes just outputs as actual text.

```
def exportPDf(results, css, html):

      result = StringIO.StringIO()

      results_2 = StringIO.StringIO(results.encode("UTF-8"))
      css_encode = StringIO.StringIO(css.encode("UTF-8"))

      pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(results_2 , result)#ISO-8859-1

      if not pdf.err:
          return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
      return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))

def get_data(request):
      results = request.GET['css'] + request.GET['html']
      html = request.GET['html']
      css = request.GET['css']
      return ExportPDf(results, css, html)
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986831/css-not-rendered-by-pisas-pdf-generation-in-django

Comment: Yes I've read a bunch of related questions,including that one, but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `css_encode` anywhere.  Try including that in your pisa call with `results_2` and `result`.

Comment: results_2 encodes results, which contains both CSS and HTML (from get_data). So if I include css_encode in PISA, it's including the CSS twice...I think. Should I NOT be combining CSS and HTML into one variable? And I did try to include it anyways like you suggested and got a "CStringIO.StringIO object has no attribute 'find'" error.