# Python pisa/xhtml2pdf messy rendering

Tags: python, html, css, django, pdf

In a django project, I want to generate an html page from a view and convert the html/css generated to pdf. I am using xhtml2pdf for this (https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/usage.rst#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django).

Browser -> django view -> mysql DB -> django template -> html/css -> pdf

I have made sure that:

- I am using a function (link_callbak) to convert all relative paths to a proper absolute ones so xhtml2pdf is able to retrieve all the images needed.
- Instead of relying on a  tag to include the CSS (which does not work) I have directly used @import function with an absolute path to the css file. ([CSS not rendered by Pisa's pdf generation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986831/css-not-rendered-by-pisas-pdf-generation-in-django))

The css file is taken into account as I find some style element in the output howver the pdf generated is very different from the html output. Images are all messed up (partly visible and partly just outside the document), forms are not respected, font size is not correct, `<ul>` are not properly rendered. Moreover, I had to remove a -moz-placeholder tag from the CSS as it was not properly handeled by xhtml2pdf.

Is there known issues of CSS interpretation with xhtml2pdf ? Is there restrictions ?
I already spent a lot of time customizing the CSS file to make it work on Chrome/Firefox and IE7, and I don't want to spend another round on adapting it for xhtml2pdf. Is there a reliable solution to convert an html/CSS templated through django to pdf ? Even a special type of link to call the 'print pdf' function of the browser would do...

And no, I don't want to use ReportLab and draw squares and circles, thank you !

Comment: the css used by pisa is limited, see item 6 at - http://xhtml2pdf.appspot.com/static/pisa-en.html for a list of supported styles

Comment: Man, things got so much better, when we dropped xhtml2pdf and pisa for  phantomjs (http://tmanstwobits.com/convert-your-web-pages-to-pdf-files-using-phantomjs.html). not really helpful comment in your case, but you might like the results.