# HTML to PDF also with keeping the CSS & bootstrap styling in Django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to render an **HTML** page into PDF in **Django** by following this GitHub tutorial [link](https://github.com/divanov11/django-html-2-pdf).

My **views.py**:

```
def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
    return path

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
    
    
class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdf = render_to_pdf('app/pdfpage.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')


#Automaticly downloads to PDF file
class DownloadPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        pdf = render_to_pdf('app/pdfpage.html', data)

        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341233")
        content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
```

However I almost copy all the code from that tutorial [link](https://github.com/divanov11/django-html-2-pdf) except **pdfpage.html**, I put there my custom made HTML page also with bootstrap and CSS styling. Now my problem is after converting and saving this pdf, it lost all the styling and bootstrap styling stuff, but those are also important for me. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986831/css-not-rendered-by-pisas-pdf-generation-in-django which should help!

Comment: I tried that technique, but actually, I cannot understand how that method works. should I just add **fetch_resources** function? (edited in the question)